# How to get previous date record of the most recent date record in PSQL

Tags: date, window-functions, pervasive

Table: Contract_Price
Columns: Customer, Part, Location, Currency, Price, Effective_date

Case: Need to get the most recent Price of Part# by the effective date. (Which I am able to get it) but also need to get the Price previous to the most recent effective date in the same row.

Example: [image]

Required: [image]

Note: This is needed for the sales team to review and compare the most recent contract price with the previous price in contract.

Executed:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT CUSTOMER,
       PART,
       LOCATION,
       DATE_EFFECTIVE,
       PRICE,
       LAG(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY PART
                        ORDER BY DATE_EFFECTIVE) PRIOR_DATE,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PART
                    ORDER BY DATE_EFFECTIVE DESC) RANK                  
FROM 
V_OE_C_PART_PRICE ) A
WHERE A.RANK = 1
```

Error: [image]

Comment: You've tagged this question with three separate database engines.  Are you really using all three?  So you need a single query that works identically in SQL Server, MySQL, and PostgreSQL?  What versions of each?

Comment: Use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` (not applicable to MySQL 5.x).

Comment: You edited the question to remove the last database tag.  You added back psql which is for questions related to the interactive terminal but explicitly not for questions regarding PostgreSQL itself.  Neither of those changes make sense to me.  If this is really a question having to do with the terminal and not the database, please provide some context in the question itself.  And I'm not sure why you added the "pervasive" tag.

Comment: @JustinCave: according to Wikipedia, the database product seems to be called [Pervasive PSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pervasive_PSQL). I guess Ali is using "Pervasive" and isn't aware that `psql` refers to something different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ahh.  A previous comment had said that he was using PostgreSQL.  I have no idea whether Pervasive PSQL supports window functions or not.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using reasonably recent versions of SQL Server, MySQL, and PostreSQL, they should all support analytic functions (some will call them window functions) which are relatively recent additions to the SQL standard.  If so, something like this should work

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT customer_number,
           part_number,
           location,
           currency,
           price current_price,
           lag( price ) over (partition by part_number 
                                  order by effective_date) prior_price,
           effective_date,
           rank() over (partition by part_number 
                            order by effective_date desc) rnk
      FROM your_table ) a
 WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

I'm using the `rank` to pick out the most recent row.  You can probably substitute that with whatever method you're currently using to get the last row but that will probably be less efficient than using the analytic function.

Comment: I am getting an error "rank() over << ??? >>" everytime I try to run RANK() funtion.

Comment: @Ali - It would be helpful to edit your question to show the actual query you're running and the actual error you're getting.  A quick SQLFiddle link that reproduces the problem would be most helpful.  For example, here's a simplified version showing that the syntax works in PostgreSQL 9.6 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0fac34/2

Comment: I am trying to run your query in Pervasive SQL  (PSQL Control Center: Install Version 13.11.011). I don't know if the ranking function is supported in pervasive sql.